# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option on reading sql file by liquibase

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase, ddl

I'm running into the issue with liquibase parsing sql file. Looks like it does not recognize ';' as a delimiter. If I keep just one statement without ';' in the end it runs fine, but obviously I need to execute the complete set of commands.
My sql looks like that:

```
CREATE TABLE network_area (
     network_area_id   NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
     name              VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) NOT NULL );

ALTER TABLE network_area ADD CONSTRAINT network_area_pk PRIMARY KEY (network_area_id );

ALTER TABLE network_area ADD CONSTRAINT network_area__un UNIQUE ( name );
```

my liquibase plugin looks like that:

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
           <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.6.2</version>
           <configuration>                  
              <propertyFile>src/test/resources/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
              <changeLogFile>src/test/resources/liquibase/ddl/my-ddl.sql</changeLogFile>
              <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>              
           </configuration>                
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>test</phase>                                                                  
               <goals>
                 <goal>update</goal>
               </goals>
             </execution>
           </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> ```
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
> Caused by: Error : 922, Position : 121, Sql = CREATE TABLE network_area (
> network_area_id   NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
> name              VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) NOT NULL
> );
> ```

Comment: You need to add [`splitStatements`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) property to your changeSet

Comment: Tried to add changeSet.splitStatements=true in liquibase.properties and tried to add it in maven plugin configuration :       <changeSet id="sqlFile-example">
       <sqlFile dbms="oracle"
                 encoding="utf8"
                 endDelimiter=";"
                 path="src/test/resources/liquibase/ddl/my-ddl.sql"
                 relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                 splitStatements="true"
                 stripComments="true"/>
      </changeSet>
Same result

Comment: really puzzled :/ why is that such a roadblock in luquibase to parse a simple sql file

Comment: Do not post code in comments. [edit] your question. But why don't you use a "native" `<createTable>` change instead?

Comment: Try to put the whole statement on one line and avoid empty lines between new statements. `splitStatements` default value is `true` so unless you did specify it to be `false` it should be active anyways. (Side note: did you consider to use a "native" `<createTable>` just like a_horse_... mentioned?)

Comment: Thank you Jen, for the comment. Yes, I tried to put everything on one line, that did not help either. I can consider it if there is an easy way of converting my ddl into xml or json format liquibase can consume. I have a massive schema I need to create in autotest schema and manually writing it other format is not really an option for me.

Comment: I'm having a realy bad luck with this framework. I tried to generate xml following https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html and running into the issue with not finding org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer is not in the classpath, which I add when run the command (tried both absolute and relative). I think at this point I have exhausted my patience with liquiebase and try flyway. But I still welcome solutions for the problem I ran into. Thank you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name he has a point. I'm trying to use createProcedure with a file, and I'm getting the same error for a Oracle stored procedure. Definitely hard to debug the root cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with alternative, setting up flywaydb. This is my configuration example for anyone who finds it useful:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>src/test/resources/flyway/flyway.properties</configFile>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/test/resources/flyway/migration</location>
                    <location>filesystem:src/test/resources/flyway/dataload</location>
                </locations>                
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                  <version>12.2.0.1.p27350958</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
           <executions>
             <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                    <goal>migrate</goal>
                </goals>
               <phase>test</phase>                                                                
             </execution>
           </executions>                
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `splitStatements` in a `<sql>` tag like this:

```
<sql 
endDelimiter=";"
splitStatements="true"
stripComments="true">

CREATE TABLE network_area (
 network_area_id   NUMBER(18) NOT NULL,
 name              VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) NOT NULL );

</sql>
<sql 
endDelimiter=";"
splitStatements="true"
stripComments="true">

ALTER TABLE network_area ADD CONSTRAINT network_area_pk PRIMARY KEY (network_area_id );

</sql>
<sql 
endDelimiter=";"
splitStatements="true"
stripComments="true">

ALTER TABLE network_area ADD CONSTRAINT network_area__un UNIQUE ( name );
</sql>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid xml, as it is an extra step for me to work. My current options are: 1) find an issue why delimiter is not recognized 2) find an easy way to convert sql into xml or json for liquibase to consume 3) swicth to flyway